# Whatsapp Bug - Voice is not sent outside of local network

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, calls, bugs, video-calling

I encountered a somehow strange problem, which leaves me in the dark. I have a Samsung S10 connected to my local WLAN. When i call my relatives - whether voice or video call - my voice and video is not send to the other person. However, when i call my other phone - also connected to the local WLAN - everything just works fine. I disconnected the phone, deleted the WLAN connection, reinstalled WhatsApp and restarted the phone, but nothing seems to work. Calling my relatives from another phone also works just as expected.

Does anybody know a solution or a something i could try?

Comment: Several network devices on your or the internet provider side (for your connection or your relatives) can block Whatsapp voice/video traffic. Make test calls with other Whatsapp contacts outside of your network to check if the problem is your network[provider] or the one of your relatives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tested it with several relatives in different locations. Every other phone in our household works fine. I can only think of a hard reset, but i really would like to know the issue.

Comment: I was speaking about tests with other Whatsapp users **outside** of your household/WiFi.